# Add a language to the script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create my own programming language. The code to create the language is as followed:

```
var printword=false;
var waitforkey=false;
function Process(text) {
    var words = text.split(/\s+/);
    var next = 0;
    this.nextWord = function () {
        if (next >= words.length) return null;
        return words[next++];
    };
}

function HackerScript() {
    var dictionary = {};

    this.stack = [];

    this.addWords = function (new_dict) {
        for (var word in new_dict)
        dictionary[word.toUpperCase()] = new_dict[word];
    };

    this.run = function (text) {
        var lexer = new Process(text);
        var word;
        var num_val;

        while (word = lexer.nextWord()) {
            while(waitforkey){
            waitforkey=false;
            }
            if(!printword){
            word = word.toUpperCase();
            }
            num_val = parseFloat(word);
            if (dictionary[word]) {
                dictionary[word](this);
            } 
            else {
                if(!printword){
                var createerror = document.createElement("p");
                createerror.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Could not process"));
                document.body.appendChild(createerror);
                }
                else{
                var print=document.createElement("p");
                print.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word));
                document.body.appendChild(print);
                printword=false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
var print = {
    "clearstack": function (terp) {
     var ensureclear=confirm("Are you sure you want to clear?");
        if(ensureclear){
     document.body.innerHTML="";
        }
    },
    "print":function(){
    printword=true;
    }
}
var wait={
    "waitkey":function(terp){
     waitforkey=true;
    }
}
var HackerScript = new HackerScript();
HackerScript.addWords(print);
HackerScript.addWords(wait);
```

The programming language can then be ran by typing

```
HackerScript.run("code words here");
```

However, I want to make executing the programming language easier for programmers. The code for the language would be executed by creating a script element with an src that points to a file with the code. But after that, the user still has to create a Javascript script tag and use the run function of the HackerScript variable. Instead, I want to add the programming language to the HTML script tag. For example:

```
<script type="text/Hackerscript">
key words here with no quotes
</script>
```

Exploring the window object helped me determine this code would need to be added to window.HTMLScriptElement, but how would I go about doing this?

Here is a link to the programming language code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey013/173g1f93/5/

Comment: Don't you think that's overdoing it a bit? Your own programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add support directly.

However, you can write code that manually finds all `<script type="text/hackerscript">` elements (using `document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/Hackerscript"]')`) and runs their `.textContent`.

Comment: I ran the code you gave me and it gave me the error                     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: @Mikey: Use the debugger to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The error is pointing at line 4 of the definition code, where I type in         var words = text.split(/\s+/); For some reason, running the text content of the document.querySelectorAll is not being processed correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you need to loop through the array.

Comment: It returns an array. That will be why it is not working. I believed it returned a string and tried to pass that. Let me see if it works with a loop.

Comment: It worked with the loop. Thanks for all the help figuring out how to get this running.